# Eclipse Memory Analyser,but always shows An internal error occurred?

Tags: java, eclipse, memory

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Dumping heap to java_pid2584.hprof ...
Heap dump file created [106948719 bytes in 4.213 secs]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2760)
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2734)
at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacity(ArrayList.java:167)
at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:351)
at Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

But when i open head dump java_pid2584.hprof via  Eclipse Memory Analyser,but there is always message:

```
An internal error occurred during: 
"Parsing heap dump from **\java_pid6564.hprof'".Java heap space
```

Comment: Did you try increasing the `-Xmx` parameter when launching Eclipse?

Comment: If you "don't have enough RAM" even when specifying -Xmx then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254017/tool-for-analyzing-large-java-heap-dumps has some ideas

Comment: I laughed so hard when my efforts to analyze a memory error failed as the tools had not enough memory. Hilarious.

Comment: To go to this file, use finder-> Macintosh hd -> Applications -> right click mat to go to contents folder -> eclipse -> MemoryAnalyzer.ini

Answer (score 145):

The problem is that Eclipse Memory Analyser does not have enough heap space to open the Heap dump file.

You can solve the problem as follows:

1. open the `MemoryAnalyzer.ini` file
2. change the default `-Xmx1024m` to a larger size

Comment: thanks for your reply,but i can't find  MemoryAnalyzer.ini file,where is the location ?

Comment: it locates in the default dir.but if you are using a eclipse plugin ,you have to enlarge the Xmx1024m of eclipse config

Comment: but the problem  is still exit when i enlarge the memory using  eclipse.exe -vmargs -Xverify:none -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:PermSize=100M -Xms256M -Xmx600M -Duser.language=en

Comment: now i find that it can parse .hprof file when less than 100M,but not when larger than 100M

Comment: This method doesn't work with the latest version of OS X (El Cap) and MemoryAnalzyer (1.5.0), see my answer below for a workaround.

Comment: This was really helpful.

Comment: In mac , MemoryAnalyzer.ini file is in /Applications/mat.app/Contents/Eclipse folder.

Answer (score 60):

Note that on OS X, to increase the memory allocated to MAT, you need to right-click `mat.app` and show the package contents. The `MemoryAnalyzer.ini` file is under `/Contents/Eclipse`.

Answer (score 17):

Solution for same issue for Memory Analyzer plugin in Eclipse in MAC OS X El Capitan.

I was facing the same issue but with the eclipse plugin and I did not have any Memory Analyzer App in Applications Folder. The solution which worked for me was:

1. Right Click on Eclipse icon and select Show Package Content.
2. Go to Contents>Eclipse
3. Open Eclipse.ini
4. Change value -Xmx1024m to -Xmx2048m
5. Restart Eclipse

Comment: Yes, If you have installed the MAT plugin in your eclipse you will need to increase the Memory in eclipse.ini under -Xmx as per your dump file.

Answer (score 14):

On OS X 11.5 (El Cap) modifying `MemoryAnalyzer.app/Contents/MacOS/MemoryAnalyzer.ini` does not work! This is because it's looking for the `MemoryAnalyzer.ini` in a different place.

On my computer, it was looking for:

`MemoryAnalyzer.app/Contents/Eclipse/MemoryAnalyzer.ini` but the real .ini file was: 
`MemoryAnalyzer.app/Contents/MacOS/MemoryAnalyzer.ini`.

In order for your changes to take effect, copy the existing `.ini` file into the new location.

To find where MemoryAnalyzer is looking for the ini file, you can run:

```
sudo su
cd ...MemoryAnalyzer.app/Contents/MacOS/
dtruss ./MemoryAnalyzer 2>&1 | grep ini
```

Comment: You can explicitly grep for `MemoryAnalyzer.ini`, as there are some other `ini` files that will show up and confuse you.

Comment: If it doesn't work, 
try
`./MemoryAnalyzer -vmargs -Xmx5g -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit` inside your `mat.app/Contents/MacOS/`

Answer (score 8):

For my experience add in **MemoryAnalyzer.ini**, Xms and Xmx to the max as your materiel possibilities. G1GC is faster and -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit is need because gc usage can be high and time consuming, and maybe -XX:+UseStringDeduplication is the key to consume less memory

```
-vmargs
-Xms8g
-Xmx8g
-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
```

Comment: works flawlessly! To go to this file, use finder-> Macintosh hd -> Applications -> right click mat to go to contents folder -> eclipse -> MemoryAnalyzer.ini

Comment: This should be way higher, it significantly decreased processing time.

Answer (score 6):

If Memory Analyser is used from Eclipse, then edit your eclipse.ini file to increase the vm argument to -Xmx1024m or higher. This worked for me.
http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/MemoryAnalyzer/FAQ#Out_of_Memory_Error_while_Running_the_Memory_Analyzer

Answer (score 5):

As suggested by others, its two step simple process:-

1. open the MemoryAnalyzer.ini file from your MAT installation directory.
2. change the default -Xmx1024m to a larger size for e.g. if you have to analyze a 4GB heap dump then you can replace -Xmx1024m with -Xmx5g or -Xmx6g

For more details refer:-
https://better-coding.com/solved-eclipse-mat-java-heap-space-error/

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Mac, try running the executable inside the mat.app 'folder' with -data option, by which you can specify a writable path:

```
cd mat.app/Contents/MacOS
./MemoryAnalyzer -data <writable_path>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the solutions here as well, while still getting the same error and the reason eclipse was trying to open the .hprof file as a text file due to wrong or unknown file type / editor association.

Solution: Right click on the file, select open with, then select Others, and select Eclipse Memory Analyzer.

Worked with 700MB dump, and worked with 2G dump on an eclipse heap of about 600M.

Answer (score -2):

An internal error has occurred. Java heap space

Ans: GO to Your Project Work space
open .setting folder
Delete all file of .setting folder.
after you can compile 
now there is  no error Like Heap space 
Enjoy :)

Answer (score -3):

You may reduce your application memory limit, and then again take a dump. Eclipse Memory Analyser puts dump file to memory - I suspect that your Eclipse has less memory than the limit of application.

You can also do the opposite and increase the memory limit for Eclipse, but if your application works on a server, it will be hard to match in size of memory.

Comment: MAT does _not_ have the complete `.hprof` in memory! I have memory dumps that are 3GB large which I can analyse in my 1G Eclipse instance...

Comment: really?but when i open 200M .hprof file,there is always error.

Comment: My solve is exactly the same as Codeisee. MAT always have problems with the analysis of large files. Look to: http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/MemoryAnalyzer/FAQ#Out_of_Memory_Error_while_Running_the_Memory_Analyzer. "Well, analyzing big heap dumps can also require more heap space. Give it some more memory"