# Eclipse MAT Parsing 11GB Heap dump - Out Of Memory. Unable to parse the heap dump

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I was trying to parse the 11GB heap dump using Eclipse MAT and I am getting the following error

```
  An internal error occurred during: "Parsing heap dump"
```

I think the MAT is unable to parse such a huge heap dump. I read some posts and increase the VM configurations to more than 80% of the dump size. Following are my vm configurations

```
      -vmargs -Xms8192m -Xmx10240m
```

and I am still not able to load the dump. I tried with ParseHeapDump.bat with no changes ...

Comment: I have more large heap dump, just create an ec2 instance to run mat in the vnc. In this case m1.xlarge or m3.2xlarge may be enough.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254017/tool-for-analyzing-large-java-heap-dumps

Comment: In general, you need more memory to parse the heap dump then is the size of the heap dump itself. 150% percent is usually enough in my experience.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Keep increasing `Xmx` till the JVM complains, then increase your swap file size, then increase `Xmx` again, etc.

At that stage it will take ages because it will be using disk as RAM.

Comment: After posting this question I tried with 12gb of heap and the dump processed but its taking very long to remove the unreachable objects. It started it since more than a day now and its still 34%. So my next question is how to speed up this process?

Answer (score 8):

I recently installed Eclipse MAT (Eclipse Memory Analyzer Version 1.9.1) on Mac OS Catalina (10.15.3). I needed to review a 4g heap dump. The default JVM heap size for MAT is 1024m.

I think the easiest way to increase the JVM's heap size is to use a shell window - go to the /Applications/mat.app/Contents/Eclipse/ folder. Then vi MemoryAnalyzer.ini and change -Xmx1024m to your required value, in my case I went with -Xmx10g.

To review the change, restart MAT and go to the help -> About Eclipse Memory Analyzer then click installation details, and look for the entry: eclipse.vmargs=-Xmx10g about 50 lines down.

Answer (score 3):

This setup worked for me.

I also recently installed Eclipse MAT to analyze a `4.85GB` heap dump file.

```
Eclipse Memory Analyzer Version: 1.11.0
MacOS Catalina: 10.15.7
Hardware Memory: 16GB
Heap dump file size: 4.85GB 
Heap dump file type: PHD
Classes: 33.6k
Objects: 4.8m
Class Loader: 575
```

I changed the `MemoryAnalyzer.ini` to `14GB` as follows:

```
-vmargs
-Xmx14g
```

I also confirmed the configuration as follows:

1. `Help -> About Eclipse Memory Analyzer 1.11.0`
2. Clicked on `Installation Details`
3. Clicked on `Configuration` tab
4. Looked for `eclipse.vmargs=-Xmx14g`.

It took some minutes to load this 4.85 heap dump file.

**Note:** I unsuccessfully tried `Xmx` setup with 2g, 4g, 8g, 10g, 12g - all failed with JVM out-of-memory in the Eclipse MAT tool.

Answer (score 0):

On the Windows install of Eclipse Photon, I got around the problem by updating the memory parameters in the eclipse.ini file. This was directly under my `c:\eclipse` folder.

```
-Xms6g 
-Xmx6g
```

I tried setting it to 4 gigs for a memory dump that was about 4.1GB and it failed. So, the rule of thumb is to set it to a higher value than the size of the memory dump.