# Large HPROF file

Tags: java, profiling, out-of-memory, jprofiler, hprof

I have a very large Heap Dump (.hprof) file (16GB). When I try to open it in Visual Vm,the VM just hangs. I tried to open it in JProfiler. Jprofiler gave me a Out Of Memory error. Below is  how my jprofiler.vmoptions looks like. What should be the ideal configuration, I should be using in order to open the HPROF without issues? I am running on a 8GB Linux box.

-Xmx1536m
-XX:MaxPermSize=128m
-Xss2m

Comment: Can you run a 64-bit JVM?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen How does it matter?

Comment: The answer might be just get a machine with RAM more then 16GB?

Comment: Is there no concept of Paging within the JVM?

Comment: You are running out of memory.  Your arguments indicate you use a 32-bit JVM.  Use a 64-bit JVM instead which can utilize more than 4 GB RAM. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1434901/53897

Comment: And to answer your question.  The JVM delegates paging to the operating system.  If an individual application needs more than that, it must implement it itself.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Spot on. I was indeed using 32bit JVM. I will try with a 64 bit JVM.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tool for analyzing large Java heap dumps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254017/tool-for-analyzing-large-java-heap-dumps)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JProfiler 8.1 will be able to open much larger HPROF files without tuning the -Xmx VM parameter. To get a pre-release, please contact support@ej-technologies.

Comment: Thnx Ingo for the answer. but is it possible to open larger files on smaller machines. so fundamentally, can I open a 16GB HPROF on a 8 G machine? My assumption is since it is a heap dump, so i would require a 16GB machine to open it up?

Comment: Ingo, I am using a licensed Jprofiler8. Am I eligible for 8.1 or there is a separate license fee for that?

Comment: Opening heap snapshots with larger heap sizes than local memory will be much better with JProfiler 8.1, although it may still take a long time. Your license key will work with 8.1.