# How to break java heap dump into smaller parts?

Tags: java, heap-dump

I have a heap dump of 48 GB but only 10 GB of machine to debug that dump.

Is there any way to break the heap dump into smaller files.

Comment: Not exactly what you're asking, but [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7254494/1361506) another strategy for analyzing large dumps that you can't debug directly.

Comment: If nothing else works you can add more swap to the system for the duration of the analysis. Use the fastest disk you can.