# Analyze remote large heap dump

Tags: java, jvm, heap-dump

I'm having Java heap dump with about 70 GB in remote Debian machine, I can't analyse it in my local machine using MAT, although I can get an overview and suspicious leak reports as HTML pages, but they are brief and there are href for the objects there that don't point to anything (maybe MAT doesn't mean to create actual links there but just for styling purposes).

However, is there anyway to fully analyze a heap dump of that size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't run MAT on that server, then you might want to run a `jhat` utility.

It will run the web server on a port (that you can override) and will provide a web console and query language called OQL (object query language) that you can use to analyze the heap dump. It looks somewhat like SQL.

Here is an example:

```
jhat -J-Xmx32g -port 7000 <PATH_TO_HEAPDUMP>
```

And then access in browser:

```
http://<IP>:7000
```

There are many tutorials about OQL, [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/querying-java-heap-with-oql) is one of them

Answer (score 0):

you can use headless MAT analyzer script to check top component ( using org.eclipse.mat.api:top_components ), that may help.

If Leak suspect doesn't tell enough then top components can give insight that which bean is occupying more space. So you can check the methods associated with that.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76298700/5140851