java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space while training OpenNLP model in Spring Boot
I'm working on a Spring Boot application that uses Apache OpenNLP to train a sentence detector model from a large text file. However, I'm encountering a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error during the training process.
Here's the relevant part of my code:
public void trainModel(String trainingFilePath, String modelFilePath, String language) throws IOException {
    try (InputStream trainingFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(trainingFilePath);
         BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(trainingFileInputStream);
         ObjectStream<String> lineStream =
                 new PlainTextByLineStream(new MarkableFileInputStreamFactory(new File(trainingFilePath)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
         ObjectStream<SentenceSample> sampleStream = new SentenceSampleStream(lineStream)) {

        SentenceDetectorFactory factory = new SentenceDetectorFactory(language, true, null, null);
        SentenceModel model = SentenceDetectorME.train(language, sampleStream, factory, TrainingParameters.defaultParams());

        try (OutputStream modelOut = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(modelFilePath))) {
            model.serialize(modelOut);
        }
    }
}

I've tried increasing the JVM heap size using the -Xmx option, but I still encounter the error with very large datasets. I'm wondering if there's a better way to handle this or if there's an optimization I can apply to reduce memory usage.
Steps Taken:

Increased JVM heap size to 2GB with -Xmx2g.
Verified that the file being processed is quite large, potentially causing the memory issue.

I considered using memory profiling tools to identify heavy memory consumers, but I wanted to ask for advice on the best approach before proceeding.

How did you determined that 2GB is the right value? Why not 8GB, or 32GB? Share the full exception message and stack trace of the error. What is the size of file? You should capture a heap dump at the error (Java can generate one automatically) and analyze it (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254017/tool-for-analyzing-large-java-heap-dumps).

"I considered using memory profiling tools to identify heavy memory consumers, but I wanted to ask for advice on the best approach before proceeding." - My advice: use a profiler.   But bear in mind that it could tell you that you actually just need a larger heap.

my file size is 12GB but my system configuration is 8GB

So you can't do anything. If the file that will be loaded is 12Gb, you know it will be read and so be put on RAM. So just buy more ram maybe, or find a way to split the file into multiple smaller one

sure, let me try that one thanks : )
